# Drop an element from a list (drop row from list of lists)

Tags: python, list, if-statement, conditional-statements, remove-if

I have a 2d array like this one:

```
list_of_data = [
    ['Joe', 4, 4, 4, 5, 'cabbage', None], 
    ['Joe', 43, '2TM', 41, 53, 'cabbage', None],
    ['Joe', 24, 34, 44, 55, 'cabbage', None],
    ['Joe', 54, 37, 42, 85, 'cabbage', None],

    ['Tom', 7, '2TM', 4, 52, 'cabbage', None],
    ['Tom', 4, 24, 43, 52, 'cabbage', None],
    ['Tom', 4, 4, 4, 5, 'cabbage', None],

    ['Fred', 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
    ['Fred', 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
    ['Fred', 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
]
```

I am interested in the rows containing the value `'2TM'` at its 2nd index. For example:

- Joe has the value `'2TM'` at index 2 in the 2nd appearance of his data.
- Tom has the value `'2TM'` at index 2 in the 1st appearance of his data.

Each time the value `'2TM'` appears in the data, I want to remove the next two rows. The example above would become the following:

```
list_of_data = 
    ['Joe', 4, 4, 4, 5, 'cabbage', None], 
    ['Joe', 43, '2TM', 41, 53, 'cabbage', None],

    ['Tom', 7, '2TM', 4, 52, 'cabbage', None],

    ['Fred', 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
    ['Fred', 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
    ['Fred', 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
]
```

I've tried using `list.pop` like so:

```
for row[x] in list_of_data:
    if '2TM' in row:
        list_of_data.pop[x+1:x+2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do something like this

```
list_of_data = [['Joe', 4, 4, 4, 5, 'cabbage', None], 
['Joe', 43,'2TM', 41, 53, 'cabbage', None],
['Joe', 24, 34, 44, 55, 'cabbage', None],
['Joe', 54, 37, 42, 85, 'cabbage', None],

['Tom', 7,'2TM', 4, 52, 'cabbage', None],
['Tom', 4, 24, 43, 52, 'cabbage', None],
['Tom', 4, 4, 4, 5, 'cabbage', None],

['Fred', 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
['Fred', 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
['Fred', 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage']]
x=0
for row in list_of_data:
    if '2TM' in row:
        list_of_data.pop(x+1)
        list_of_data.pop(x+1)
    x+=1
print(list_of_data)
```

You were quite close but just missed the increment of x.

Comment: `list.pop` will fail if there aren't two rows (or even one) after the row containing `'2TM'`. For example, if the last row (or second-to-last) of `list_of_data` contained a `'2TM'`, `list.pop` would raise an exception.

Comment: He mentioned that next two rows need to be deleted. Although a check could be applied for last rows

Comment: @ZachGates I understand your objection here. And for general purposes, you are right: this method would raise an objection in the scenario you describe. However, the inherent/unique nature of my dataset is that any time 2TM appears in my data, there are always 2 rows that need to be removed. So this .pop method actually worked for my data even as it may not work for general purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop:

```
index = 0

while index < len(list_of_data):
    if list_of_data[index][2] == '2TM':
        # check if the names are the same, as needed
        del list_of_data[index + 1:index + 3] 

    index += 1
```

Comment: This methods works equally as well as the one below. Thanks very much for your input.